# Modeling decision table in Oracle database

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a requirement an input form say x needs to be routed to a bucket based on some criteria, and the criteria might vary for each form.

For example, if form X with Language= English, Year=1997 and State=NY will be routed to bucket Y.

if form Y with Language= English, Year=1998 and State=NY will be routed to bucket Z.

The criteria Language, Year, State might be present for some form and for some forms Year wil not be present.

Simillarly , for form XY, there will beother set of criterias.

We want to make it configurable and want to store these values in Database. This is more like a decision table.

I want to know what is the best way to implement it

Comment: You want the help regarding DB design or regarding the java implementation?
Are you using any ORM-framework like Hibernate?
Can you please specify the unique constraint too, as per my understanding it should Form, Language, YEar and State.
Bucket is another form?

Comment: From my point of view, that looks like a single table with 5 columns: form, language, year, state, bucket. There might be foreign key constraints to form, language, state and bucket tables, though. So - 5 tables, in total.

Comment: @Garima- I need help in DB design.

Comment: @Littlefoot-If the number of criterias increases, then adding anothe column would not make sense

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way here is to create a table with criterias as your column:
Form            Language        Year       State      Bucket

But if your criterias are going to be different for each combination, then I think the best way could be to create the tables with below mentioned columns
Form          CriteriaName       CriteriaValue          Bucket
X             Language             English                Y
X             State                  NY                   Y
X             Year                  1998                  Y

I would suggest the best way will be the approach-1 with criterias as your column. But if your criterias changes frequently then this could be the approach.
Definitely approach-2 will require more work on Java side to build a neat solution